# Why am i not deserialize the Json to DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I have used below json string to deserialize as DataTable

```
string json = "[{\"clientID\":\"1788\",\"projectID\":\"19\"}]";
var data = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

But i got the below exception

[image]

if i have tried to deserialize using List which has deserialzed successfully.

```
var dat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Client>>(json);
```

But i want to Deserialize using DataTable.

Please suggest me if i have missed anything

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of the exception, but text, including the stacktrace. You can see when clicking at "View Detail..."

Comment: Was this object serialized using as a source a DataTable object? Otherwise it won't have the proper serialization format to convert it to a DataTable

Comment: you cannot directly converter JSON to system.DataTable format, you need to set class for the same.

Comment: Try removing the outer square brackets. Or adding extra figure brackets around.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have tried like this but still i am facing the issue **string json = "{{\"clientID\":\"1788\",\"projectID\":\"19\"}}";**

Answer (score 1):

You need to create class for your JSON object, in my case I can give you example..

```
public class TagValueConfig
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int MinTagValue { get; set; }
    public int MaxTagValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize it to object array

```
 TagValueConfig[] ObjTagConfigData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TagValueConfig[]>(ConfigTagString);
```

once you get Deserialize array, convert it to DataTable format..

or use Extension method.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: The json string has no fixed structure. Your way doesn't work

Comment: @LêDuyThứ in that case you need to have dynamic object just replace TagValueConfig[] with dynamic[] and you are done

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deserialize  a `List<T>` to a `DataTable`. Instead you can first get a `List<T>` and then convert it to `DataTable`.

This: [Converting a List to a DataTable](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/226720/Converting-a-List-to-a-DataTable) could be a good staring point.

The code from the article:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
        {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a List to a datatable
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
            {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
                {
                PropertyDescriptor property = properties[i];
                dt.Columns.Add(property.Name, property.PropertyType);
                }
            object[] values = new object[properties.Count];
            foreach (T item in data)
                {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                    {
                    values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(item);
                    }
                dt.Rows.Add(values);
                }
            return dt;
            }
        }
```

With the generic code from the article you can do something like:

```
var dat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Client>>(json);
```

and then to convert:

```
var dataTable = dat.ToDataTable();
```